# 16.04: Virtualbox Installation in Chromebook

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I am the definition of a beginner when it comes to this. I need to install virtualbox for a class and I am lost. First I installed Linux on my chromebook. I type in `virtualbox`, and it opens but I receive the message,

```
The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-geab5e6346fdb.

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. If possible, please explain as simply as possible how to proceed, as I am entirely new to this and I really want to get this installed properly. I will even uninstall everything and start over if necessary. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you install VB? Are linux-headers installed?

Comment: I installed it using the method in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGVt37HFNpo). I only followed the video and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I re-flashed my Acer Chromebook with `SeaBIOS` and installed the latest Ubuntu on it (18.04). It works fine, though it doesn't have 'sleep' mode. I'm not sure if that is due to the hardware or the 'SeaBIOS'.

Maybe that's an option rather than using Virtualbox.